# Destroy spawned objects on touch Corona SDK

Tags: android, sdk, coronasdk

I want destroy objects by touching them that I spawn every 1 sec randomly in the screen.
I wrote something but it destroys only the first object that spawns.
I am very noob at this things, someone can help me please?
I wrote this code: (thunder is my object)

```
local thunder = display.newImageRect( "thunder_icon.png",100,100)
thunder.x = larghezza / 2
thunder.y = altezza / 2
local spawnTimer

local function myToccoListener(event)
    display.remove(thunder)
    return true
end

local spawn = function()
    local xCoord = math.random(display.contentWidth * 0, display.contentWidth * 1.0)
    local thunder = display.newImageRect( "thunder_icon.png",100,100)
    thunder.x = xCoord
    thunder.y = 50
    thunder:addEventListener("touch", myToccoListener)
end
spawnTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, spawn, -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever the code you have is correct, just do this one modification.

```
 local thunder = display.newImageRect( "thunder_icon.png",100,100)
 thunder.x = larghezza / 2
  thunder.y = altezza / 2
 local spawnTimer

local function myToccoListener(event)
   -- display.remove(thunder)
    if event.target then 
       event.target:removeSelf()
       return true
    end 
end

local spawn = function()
   local xCoord = math.random(display.contentWidth * 0, display.contentWidth * 1.0)
  local thunder = display.newImageRect( "thunder_icon.png",100,100)
  thunder.x = xCoord
  thunder.y = 50
  thunder:addEventListener("touch", myToccoListener)
end
spawnTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, spawn, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this:

```
local spawnTimer

local spawn = function()
    local xCoord = math.random(display.contentWidth * 0, display.contentWidth * 1.0)
    local thunder = display.newImageRect( "thunder_icon.png",100,100)
    thunder.x = xCoord
    thunder.y = 50
    local function myToccoListener(event)
    display.remove(thunder)
    return true
    end
    thunder:addEventListener("touch", myToccoListener)
end

spawnTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, spawn, -1)
```